# Windows batch file - automatic answer to all prompts

Tags: windows, batch-file, return, prompt

I am running a program that generates a batch file. The batch file has a bunch of prompts that I want to answer with RETURN:

Example:

```
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed
```

I have tried:

```
echo. | batchfile.bat
```

This only answers the first prompt. I want to answer all prompts, and there are a lot of prompts.

Comment: Your program generates a batch file? So you have a batch file, end of story.
Do you mean that your batch file is running a program? Or a program is running a batch file?

Comment: The program generates the batch file. I have a server which will run the batch file that is generated every night. The batch file contains a bunch of prompts. How do I run the batch file, answering all prompts with RETURN

Comment: load up a txt file with at least as many returns as you have prompts, then `type file.txt| batchfile.bat`?

Comment: awesome that worked! Thank you so much! Put it as an answer and i'll put it as best answer

Comment: `batchfile.bat < NUL`

Comment: @Aacini `batchfile.bat < NUL` is the same as `type nul | batchfile.bat` i.e. empty answer to all `set /P` prompts in batch…

Comment: @JosefZ: Well, _functionally_ is the same, but the pipe version execute two copies of `cmd.exe` file, so it is _much_ less efficient...

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways to do it.
 1. As @MarcB mentioned in the comment you can create a file with as much returns as you need, then use the `type file.txt| batchfile.bat` command
 2. Similar like the 1st one, but the command is: `batchfile.bat < file.txt`
 3. Chaining commands (answer with 3 returns): `(echo.&echo.&echo.) | batchfile.bat` normally, this also can be formatted like this:

```
(
  echo.
  echo.
  echo.
) | batchfile.bat
```

Also if your answer (in your case not) contains some special character which is an operation like `&` `|` `>` `<` you will need to escape them with `^` sign. Like `(echo Stan ^& Pan&echo old series)` result will be in this case:

```
Stan & Pan
old series
```

Side note: Also I don't know what was your usage, but if I had access to modify that batch file, than I would add a new option (like `y`) and if that option is present, I don't ask anything in the batch file and I answer the question inside the batch file (if there's other programs which asks something). This will make a bit easier the script usage (like: `batchfile.bat y`).